# aspnet core 1.0 full .net framework on Linux

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linux, mono, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a few simple questions:

a) can I use mono on linux and osx to load the full .net framework like I would on windows by adding net46 to my project.json?

b) can I use mono as an alias like net46?

c) can I use mono with aspnet core 1.0 rtm projects on linux?

I have been looking at the dotnet docs, specifically the standard library and the table and the table with the platform support confuses me with the arrows and star under mono. 
thanks

Comment: Mono is best effort. It is known that some things don't currently work. Why not use .NET Core?

Comment: Some basic things don't work on net core, like server side image processing so i figured use mono to load the full .net on my linux server hosting my application. But it looks like that isn't possible huh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> can I use mono on linux and osx to load the full .net framework like I would on windows by adding net46 to my project.json?

In theory, yes, that's exactly what you do: specify some version of `net` inside `frameworks` in your project.json and [`dotnet run` will then use mono to run your application](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/blob/v1.0.0-preview2/src/dotnet/commands/dotnet-run/RunCommand.cs#L165-L175).

In practice, basic Hello World application works, but I'm not sure how well will more complicated applications work.

If you want to run `dotnet build` on the same machine, you will also need reference assemblies. The version I tested (mono 4.2.1) only contained reference assemblies up to .Net 4.5.1, so `net451` works, but `net46` doesn't.

> can I use mono as an alias like net46?

I don't think you can, at least not without forking .Net Core SDK.

I don't understand why would you want to do that, but I believe doing so would require modifying [`DefaultFrameworkMappings` in NuGet.Client](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet.Client/blob/62aac7df1f4e67b3cb099bc6fc48abc1c8bb3f3a/src/NuGet.Core/NuGet.Frameworks/DefaultFrameworkMappings.cs).

> can I use mono with aspnet core 1.0 rtm projects on linux?

I wasn't able to make a basic ASP.NET Core application run under mono. I don't know what the problem is, or how hard would it be to fix it. **EDIT**: [I managed to work around the issue I encountered.](https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/205)

Comment: i will accept ur response as my answer cos i had my reservations about what was possible with aspnet core. This simply makes it clear to me that i might not be able to do what i need with it. I need server side image processing for example and that is not available except I'm mistaken so i don't know why DotNet was tagged 1.0 when it still feels and looks like a beta, with incomplete parts. Anyways thanks for your response

Comment: @Eagletrophy Turns out the issue I had was not that hard to work around (see edit).

Comment: just saw d issue you opened and what i don't get is wasn't this scenario even considered as a use case by the dotnet and aspnet core teams? You could load mono runtime with dnx so has that disappeared with no trace anymore? Its just shocking to me

Answer (score 0):

Mono is other thing. Yeah they developed mono like .net framework but you cannot use .net 4.6 on mono.

Read the following article. Click [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn878908(v=vs.110).aspx)

Micrsoft developed .net core a new framework to run .net on windows, linux, mac osx etc.